# Backbone: Best way to handle variable common to all models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mvvm

I'm currently developing my first Backbone single page app project and I'm facing an issue.

Basically I have a menu (html `select` input element) implemented as a View. Its value is used to control pretty much every other data requests since it specifies which kind of data to show in the other Views.

Right now I handle the DOM event and trigger a global event so that every model can catch it and keep track internally of the new value. That's because that value is then needed when requesting new data. But this doesn't look like a good solution because A) I end up writing the same function (event handler) in every model and B) I get several models with the same variable.

```
var Metrics = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "dummy-metrics.json",
    model: MetricsItem,

    initialize: function () {
        this.metric = undefined;
    },

    setMetric: function (metric) {
        this.metric = metric;
        globalEvents.trigger("metric:change", this.get(metric));
    }
});

var GlobalComplexity = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function () {
        var url = "http://asd/global.json?metric=" + this.metric;
        return url;
    }, //"dummy-global.json",
    model: GlobalComplexyItem,

    initialize: function () {
        this.metric = undefined;

        this.listenTo(globalEvents, "metric:change", this.updateMetric);
    },

    updateMetric: function (metric) {
        this.metric = metric.get("id");
        this.fetch({ reset: true });
    }
});
```

All my other Collections are structured like `GlobalComplexity`.

What's the cleanest way to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you please add some code snippet so we can easily identify problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a global parametersManager. Export an instance (singleton) then require it when you need it.

On "globalupdate" you update the parametersManager then trigger "update" for all your model/collections so they'll look what are the current parameters in the parametersManager.

Comment: So basically a global variable is my best option?

Comment: it seems appropriate since it's a global use.